# Generate same ID out of same sets of IDs

Tags: c#, hash, ssis

I have an issue that I'll try to explain. My thought is to create a script in SSIS in C# and with that generate a list of IDs for each unique combination of IDs in a table.

I have a SQL server table which consists of two columns. The columns are IDs (I can make them numeric but in raw format they are alphanumeric strings). I want to generate a new ID out of the set of IDs in column 2 that are connected to column 1.

```
 Col1  Col2    Generated ID
   1     1
   1     2    => 1
   1     3
 -----------
   2     1    => 2
   2     3
 -----------
   3     3
   3     1    => 1
   3     2
```

I'm thinking of a Hash function maybe? But how do I get the same ID out of the set for 1 and 3? Independent of order? Do I need to sort them first?

I needed "10 reputation" to post an image so I hope my illustration explains the issue...

Comment: I would say use calculated column ( with hash and Rownumber) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696504/sql-server-2008-hashbytes-computed-column

Comment: Could you explain the logic that leads to the third generated ID becoming `1`

Comment: That is my question. How can I write a code that will generate a ID which is "unique" for a unique set of values in the second column? if the set of values are the same, it will generate the same ID.

Comment: @BrijRajSingh -Wouldn't that generate a unique ID for every set? I would like to have the same ID for the same set of values no matter in which order they are.

Comment: Ahh, so use `Col1` as the boundary marker for the set that is in `Col2`. Thus the first and third group have the same set of values (order irrelevant) in `Col2` and thus they get the same ID assigned. The second group gets a new ID as it lacks value 2. If Col1 had a value of 4 and Col2 was 3,1, then you'd assign ID 2, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As further examples to try to understand your problem, would you expect the following sets of values in Col2 to return something *like* '123' as the "Generated ID" value for all the listed cases below, like so?

Col2 =>  Generated ID

1,2,3 => 123

1,3,2 => 123

2,1,3 => 123

2,3,1 => 123

3,1,2 => 123

3,2,1 => 123

etc

If so, then based on the above assumptions and to answer your questions:

- Yes, a Hash function *could* do it
- How you get the same "Generated ID" for sets 1 and 3 (in your example) will depend on your GetHashCode() override/implementatio
- Yes, you will probably need to sort, but again, that depends on your implementation.

Since you refer to using a C# script in SSIS, a possible C# implementation might be to implement a (very!) simple Hash class which given a set of Col2 values (for each data set), simply:

1. sorts the values for Col2 to get them in the 'right' order and
2. returns some integer representation of the sorted set of data to get the Hash (e.g., concatenate the int's as strings and then convert back to int)

The hash class could be instantiated in your (base?) class's GetHashCode() function, which is passed the Col2 values and performs steps (1) and (2) above, returning the hash code as needed.

Something like this might work for you (assuming you have access to Generics in the .NET version you're using):

```
namespace SimpleHashNamespace
{
    public class SimpleHash
    {
        private readonly List<int> _data;
        public SimpleHash(List<int> col2)
        {
            _data = col2;
        }

        public int GetMyHash()
        {
            _data.Sort();
            string stringHash = string.Join("", _data);
            return int.Parse(stringHash);   // warning 1: assumes you always have a convertible value
        }
    }

    public class MyDataSet
    {
        private readonly List<int> _dataSetValues;

        public MyDataSet(List<int> dataSetValues)
        {
            _dataSetValues = dataSetValues;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            SimpleHash simpleHash = new SimpleHash(_dataSetValues);
            return simpleHash.GetMyHash();   // warning 2: assumes the computed hash can fit into the int datatype given that GetHashCode() has to return int 
        }
    }

    public partial class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // how you split up Col1 to get your list of int's dataset is up to you
            var myDataSet1 = new MyDataSet(new List<int>(new int[] { 1,2,3 }));
            Console.WriteLine(myDataSet1.GetHashCode());

            var myDataSet2 = new MyDataSet(new List<int>(new int[] { 2,1,3 }));
            Console.WriteLine(myDataSet2.GetHashCode());

            var myDataSet3 = new MyDataSet(new List<int>(new int[] { 3,2,1 }));
            Console.WriteLine(myDataSet3.GetHashCode());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously this is a trivial implementation however given the simplicity of the problem as it has been specified, perhaps this will suffice?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE T (Col1 INT, Col2 INT);
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[T]([Col1],[Col2])
VALUES (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,3), (3,3), (3,1), (3,2), (2,3),(2,1);
GO

SELECT 
    T1.Col1,
    ( 
       SELECT Convert (VARCHAR,Col2)  + ','
       FROM T T2
       WHERE T2.Col1 = T1.Col1
       ORDER BY Col2
       FOR XML PATH('') 
    ) AS Col2_Cat
INTO X
FROM T T1
GROUP BY Col1 ;


SELECT T.Col1, T.Col2,  Y.Col3
FROM T
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT X1.Col1, Min (X2.Col1) AS Col3  FROM X X1
    ----inner join X X2 on HASHBYTES ('SHA1',X1.Col2_Cat) = HASHBYTES('SHA1',X2.Col2_Cat)
    inner join X X2 on X1.Col2_Cat = X2.Col2_Cat
    GROUP BY X1.Col1
) AS Y
ON T.Col1 = Y.Col1;


DROP TABLE X
DROP TABLE T
```