# Adding hash column to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, hash

I'm trying to hash the columns of some tables using SHA256 and store the hashed value. I'm thinking of using `HASHBYTES` to achieve this but the function can only take one string argument as the hash input - `HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', COLUMN_1)`. Is it possible to hash multiple columns (including ones that are not strings)?

The reason I want to do this is so I can identify rows that have been changed or added using the hash value to later use in an ETL process. One of the tables I want to hash contains these columns:

```
[CompanyCode] [varchar](4) NULL,
[CompanyNumber] [int] NULL,
[CompanyDescription] [varchar](20) NULL,
[CompanyAddress] [varchar](60) NULL,
[EffectiveDate] [date] NULL
```

**Note that I cannot add a timestamp with a trigger since the table is managed by a third party.**

Comment: Why not a timestamp instead. (Triggers!!!)

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that the table is controlled by a third-party app and I cannot modify it. I just made a copy of it that I'm working off.

Comment: What do you mean you can't modify it? You stated that you want to add a new column or are you saying you want to create a new table to hold the hashbytes value?

Comment: Unless security is a bigtime issue, couldn't you just use a version of `checksum(*)`?

Comment: The latter. I wanted to make a new table that holds an additional hashbytes column.

Comment: You can concatenate the columns together or use `checksum()`.

Comment: Okay, I will try that. Thanks for the help so far

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3696556/314291) is related - you could create a persisted computed column by concatenating VACHAR representations of all your interesting columns, and then create an index on it. Of course, hashing won't necessarily be unique - once in a while you'll get a hash collision.

Comment: So you have a new table that is a copy?  How you update that table?

Answer (score 0):

I think Concatenating columns together would be your best bet and you may want to use some covert staements to get everything in the same format.

```
SELECT CompanyCode + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),CompanyNumber) + CompanyDescription + CompanyAddress
+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), EffectiveDate)
FROM your_table
```

That will give you all the informaition you want as a single string. I think when you want to hash the table you can probably use the query in place of the coulmn name in the hash function:

```
HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',<above query>)
```

Put A SELECT in front of HAHBYTES to test and make sure it works. I had to test with SHA1 but got it to work.

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256','<above query>')
```